# Can A/B testing of subscription free trial be made on iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, ab-testing, in-app-subscription

I want to A/B test free trial for auto-renewal subscription. How can I do that?

I can A/B test the app UI describing subscription, but iOS system modal screen will display free trial anyway if it is enabled in appstore connect.

The other option I think of is creating another one similar subscription in appstore connect with free trial and A/B test it with the existing one. But I doubt it will pass review. And it will be a pain to support two subscriptions from now on.

Any ideas how to perform such a test?

Answer (score 4):

To A/B test a free trial you should create two different subscriptions that are part of the same [Subscription Group](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscription-groups-explained-8c5b8325d4ab). This will ensure that a user can only be subscribed to one at a time. Apple allows this and you won't have any trouble passing review due to having multiple subscription offerings - it's a fairly common practice across subscription apps.

As far as supporting two subscriptions - if they unlock the same content in your app it shouldn't be any more work than supporting a single subscription. The only difference will be they'll have different `product_ids`.

Comment: Can that be done without all the subscriptions with different pricings appearing to the user on the AppStore settings?

Comment: You'd have to use subscriptions from different Subscription Groups for that. I'm not sure whether Apple would allow that or not since I can't find anything in the documentation related to that.